# Face replacement by an image in video using FFMPEG android

Tags: android, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I am working on FFMPEG Video Conversion, I want a face replacement by my image in a video. For this subject I searched for something which I am describing below. Please let me know if I am wrong, and suggest a more proper procedure for the task.

1) I can extract all images from a video frame by frame.

2) Then we detect face from each image.

3) Morph an image onto the face.

4) Then again make a video with these images through FFMPEG.

Am I right? If yes then what about audio in this process? And if wrong then where am I mistaken?

Comment: I have tried a FFMPEG command to extract frames per sec from a video.....but I am not able to do the rest of that..but I can do that with some R&D....but I am not sure that I am in correct way or not...or this can be implemented through any other best way.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for this but i m doing same thing with ffmpeg can you give me some guidelines ? :) thanks......

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg can help with the video/audio handling part ,for the the face replacement you need a specific image processing tool : openCV http://opencv.org/ crosses my mind but you can do further search.Good luck.